# Eclipse: how to make directory trees show as packages

Tags: eclipse, package, directory

In a typical project of mine, I have several source directories, each with the usual special icon in the package explorer.

Since these are maven projects, some are full of Java code, and some are full of resources.

Some of the resource trees show the subdirs as packages, but others just show them as folders.

Anyone know how to get them all to show as packages?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In the Package Explorer, right-click on the folder and choose *Build Path* / *Use As Source Folder*.  The contents of that folder will now be included in the Eclipse build, however.

**Edit**

If it is a nested folder, it has probably been excluded from the build.  If so, you can choose *Build Path* / *Include* -- but once again it will now be part of the build.  An included subfolder can be excluded again using *Build Path* / *Exclude*.

Answer (score 0):

Run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` from your root of project. It solved for me.

Comment: WARNING: It solved it for me but it did do undesired changes to .classpath and .project files! It is not recommended to run this command without a backup or version control system.